# Given $r(t)=\{(t- \sin t,1- \cos t) \cdots \}$ , get length of curve using integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

> Given $r(t)=\{(t- \sin t,1- \cos t), 0 \leq t \leq 2 \pi$} and $D$ is bounded by $r(t)$ and $x$ axis , let $ \alpha$ be that surface of $D$ counter clockwise.
> what is the length of $\alpha$

---

First we need $||r'(t)||$ we get $\sqrt{2-2 \cos t}= \sqrt{2} \cdot \sqrt{1-\cos t}$

so the integral is $\sqrt {2} \int_0^{2 \pi} \sqrt{1-\cos t}dt$

so now $\sqrt{1-\cos t} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{1+\cos t}}{\sqrt{1+\cos t}}$ $=$ $\frac {\sqrt{\sin^2t}}{\sqrt{1+cost}}$ $=$ $\frac {\sin t}{\sqrt{1+ \cos t}}$

but calculating this integral $\sqrt {2} \int_0^{ 2 \pi} \frac {\sin t}{\sqrt{1+ \cos t}}dt$ is zero which is wrong it should be $8$

In the solution , they simply said : $2-2 \cos t=4\sin ^2(\frac{t}{2})$ [[ text book hint ]] and from there the integral is not a problem..

Where is my mistake?
thanks for any help and tips. hopefully the translations are understandable

Comment: $\sqrt{\sin^2t}=|\sin t|$

Comment: You found the length of curve $r$, but it asked for the perimeter of $D$ - are you sure they are the same?

Comment: There are a lot of technical "wrongness" in the Post , I would have edited it , but that "wrongness" is the Crux of why you got the "wrong Conclusion" , hence editing the Question will obviate the Question. OK fine , I will give tips. [[ You are using Double Integral though there is Single variable $t$ # You have left out the $dt$ # $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$ # Have you used the X Axis Bound ? # Did you make a Diagram to check what Exactly you are Integrating ? # When $||r||$ is Positive , there is no way we can add that to get $0$. ]] You can try these tips , Answer will work out automatically.

Comment: @Prem the double integral and forgetting the $dt$ are just typos... 
I understand that $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$ but how would that change my answer ? 
I tried doing $(t-sint)^2+(1-cost^2)^2$ to see what it would look like but I did not manage to figure it out I assume it is a circle with center not at origin

Comment: When we make Initial Diagrams & Intermediate Diagrams , & when we are careful & rigorous , then we can easily go over each line to verify what Exactly we have Done. Identifying the mistakes will be easier then. I have given two Solutions with Diagrams. Do take a look & see whether it is useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Let $\;x(t)=t-\sin t\;,\;y(t)=1-\cos t\;$ for any $\,t\in[0,2\pi]\,.$

$\begin{align}\mathrm{Length}(\alpha)&=\displaystyle\int_0^{2\pi}1\,\mathrm dt+\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{x’^2(t)+y’^2(t)}\,\mathrm dt=\\[3pt]&=2\pi+\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{(1-\cos t)^2+\sin^2\!t\,}\,\mathrm dt=\\[3pt]&=2\pi+\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{2(1-\cos t)}\,\mathrm dt=\\[3pt]&=2\pi+2\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{\dfrac{1-\cos t}2}\,\mathrm dt=\\[3pt]&=2\pi+2\int_0^{2\pi}\sin\left(\dfrac t2\right)\,\mathrm dt=\\[3pt]&=2\pi+2\left[-2\cos\left(\dfrac t2\right)\right]_0^{2\pi}=\\[3pt]&=2\pi+2\big(2+2\big)=2\pi+8\,.\end{align}$

Answer (score 2):

We are given Curve $S$ , having Co-ordinates $x$ & $y$ , in terms of $t$ , which is between $0$ & $2 \pi$.

This is that Parametric Curve :

[image: CURVE]
( Image Curtesy of Wolfram )

---

A Point on the Curve $S$ is $(x,y)=(t-\sin(t),1-\cos(t))$
Curve $dS$ will be $\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2}$ ( Pythagoras theorem on the triangle with sides $dx$ & $dy$ )

Hence , Curve $dS$ will be $\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2}=\sqrt{(dx/dt)^2+(dy/dt)^2}dt$ ( Parametric )

Hence , we get $S=\int_{t=0}^{t=2\pi}dS=\int_{t=0}^{t=2\pi}\sqrt{(dx/dt)^2+(dy/dt)^2}dt$

---

**SOLUTION 1 ( using text book hint ) :**

$S=\int_{t=0}^{t=2\pi}\sqrt{(1-\cos(t))^2+(\sin(t))^2}dt$

$S=\int_{t=0}^{t=2\pi}\sqrt{2-2\cos(t)}dt$

$S=\int_{t=0}^{t=2\pi}\sqrt{4\sin^2(t/2)}dt$ ( using the given hint )

$S=\int_{t=0}^{t=2\pi}2|\sin(t/2)|dt$

$S=\int_{t=0}^{t=2\pi}2\sin(t/2)dt$ ( $|\cdot|$ is not necessary here because we have Positive values here )

$S=-4\cos(t/2)_{t=0}^{t=2\pi}$

$S=[-4\cos(t/2)]_{t=0}^{t=\pi}+[4\cos(t/2)]_{t=\pi}^{t=2\pi}$

$S=[-(-4)-(-4)]$

$S=8$

---

**SOLUTION 2 ( using your way ) :**

You got it Correct till here :
$\frac {\sqrt{2}\sin t}{\sqrt{1+ \cos t}}$
which should actually be
$\frac {\sqrt{2}|\sin t|}{\sqrt{1+ \cos t}}$ ( $|\cdot|$ is required here because Sign (of $\sin$) is not Constant )

We see that Sign (of $\sin$) is Positive when $t$ is between $0$ & $\pi$ , while Sign (of $\sin$) is Negative when $t$ is between $\pi$ & $2\pi$

Hence , we split the Integral into this :
$S=\int_0^{\pi}\frac {\sqrt{2}\sin t dt}{\sqrt{1+ \cos t}}+\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}\frac {-\sqrt{2}\sin t dt}{\sqrt{1+ \cos t}}$ ( Integrals are always Positive now )

This gives :
$S=[-2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1+\cos t}]_0^{\pi}+[2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1+\cos t}]_{\pi}^{2\pi}$

This will give :
$S=2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2}+2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2}=4+4=8$

---

In Case we want to include the Base too , it is a Straight line , hence it is $2 \pi$

Over all , Perimeter of region will be $2 \pi + 8$

---

**ADDENDUM :**

It might be useful to visualize the $|\cdot|$ Issue :

Plotting $\frac {\sqrt{2}\sin t}{\sqrt{1+ \cos t}}$ , where area (Integral) is $0$ :
[image: no |-|]
( Image Curtesy of Wolfram )

Plotting $\frac {\sqrt{2}|\sin t|}{\sqrt{1+ \cos t}}$ , where area (Integral) is not $0$ :
[image: with |-|]
( Image Curtesy of Wolfram )